# Cannot drive UIView.transition with the UIViewPropertyAnimator.fractionComplete

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

I’m trying to drive a transition of a UIImageView with 2 image values (in this example) with a slider
But using a `UIView.transition` within a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` (which is supposed to work)
it doesn’t. Am i missing something?

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3.0, curve: .linear)

let crossDissolve = {
  self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "deadpool.jpg")
  UIView.transition(
    with: self.imageView,
    duration: 4.0,
    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
    animations: {},
    completion: nil
  )
}

animator.addAnimations(crossDissolve)
```

Here is a playground with an example of the issue,
just drag the slider from one side to another and the images should cross dissolve softly

Something like:

[image: img]

Playground: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix8nfxg43ij68q3/UIViewPropertyAnimator.playground.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

In the code provided you haven't defined any animations in the animation closure, I"m not overly familiar with this API but I assume you would want something like this. (I haven't tested this code)

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3.0, curve: .linear)

let crossDissolve = {
  UIView.transition(
    with: self.imageView,
    duration: 4.0,
    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
    animations: {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "deadpool.jpg")
    },
    completion: nil
  )
}

animator.addAnimations(crossDissolve)
```

You can then use a function called on the sliders `.valueChanged` event to handle the animation progress

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged) 

func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    myAnimation.fractionComplete = CGFloat(sender.value)
}
```

Comment: thanks, the full code is in the playground, then i add the calls that you suggest